# Mail shows 100% usage for Gmail account, doesn't rebuild

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

For some reason Mail shows me 100% account usage on my Gmail account. I've deleted most mails with attachments, erased deleted items and did a rebuild. However, the account information still shows 100%, I don't get new mail and nothing seems to work. When looking at gmail.com, there's 1% used.

I've already removed the account and added it again, restarted the Mac and now I'm running out of ideas.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Is this a free gmail account with 18 Gig total space and you used all of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Quit Mail, then go to your home folder's **Library** folder (*) and move the folder **com.apple.mail** from the **Containers** folder to your desktop. Start Mail up and see what what happens - hopefully it will start behaving again. If it does, trash the folder you moved to the desktop. We've had several instances of odd Mail behaviour and trashing the Mail container has done the trick, restoring normal function.

(*) If you don't know how to access your Library folder, select the Go menu in Finder and hold down option/alt key to reveal the Library option.